# Job advert wrapping issue?

Tags: bug, design, google-chrome

I saw the following issue a few minutes ago in the image below with the link in the advert:

[image]

Edit: Seen again today (16th of May 2018 at 2.30pm GMT):
[image]

Hopefully it will help you guys out. Maybe something to do with `break-all` or `break-word` in the `word-break` property.

Comment: I have just seen this issue again. I am about to edit the original question.

Comment: Just seen this with a long URL on a Wikimedia advert: https://i.stack.imgur.com/seIf2.png